# How to turn NSString hexInterval into NSTimeInterval for date conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

Currently, I am working with an existing array of NSDates in the following format:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; //today is used as an example
NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *hexInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x", (int)interval];
NSLog(@"hexInterval %@", hexInterval);
```

The dates are outputted in a format such as `4ec2acf0`.

My goal is to turn these back into NSDates, as since they came from NSTimeInterval, I was wondering how I could turn it back into NSTimeIntervals given that all I have are these 8-character NSStrings.

My goal is:

```
//Turn NSString into NSTimeInterval here, then:
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code will break in 2038.

Comment: And why would you do this? NSDate is a perfectly fine time. If you need to, you convert it to an NSNumber. Why would you make your life harder by turning it into a hexadecimal string?

Comment: That's actually a very good point. Unfortunately the code handed to me only had NSStrings. I will see if I could refactor earlier codes so no details are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse hex with `NSScanner`, like this:

```
unsigned res = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexInterval];
[scanner scanHexInt:&res];
NSTimeInterval interval = (NSTimeInterval)res;
// Once you have an interval, use your code:
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

Note that this approach truncates the time portion of `NSTimeInterval`. This happens at the point when you convert `NSTimeInterval` to `int` on this line:

```
NSString *hexInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x", (int)interval];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out - yes the truncation is ok, although a bit of detail is lost.